# Importrange Query Google Sheet Include SheetName

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm using Query and Importrange to pull details from other tabs on a Google Sheet.
The other tabs are linked to individual Google Forms.
I'd like to include the name of the sheet the data came from in the query but can't figure out a way to do this.

Any ideas?

I did try having a column on each sheet that contained the name of the sheet i.e. a column on sheet1 where all the entries are sheet1. Then with the query have that column included in the selection.
However, when new Google Forms submissions are made, a new row is added (I think) and the column that contains the sheet name now has a empty entry where the new row was added.

I'm not able to share the sheet as it contains student info from school and it's not-shareable outside my organisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using a drag-down style formula within the form responses tab which would cause this rows not aligning with your already included formula as & when new responses pop in!

You could just use an arrayformula accommodated in the first row_cell itself as shown in the screenshot and it should fix this thing. Please do test it out and let us know if its solved or aint.

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A:A),"SHEET 1",))
```

- 

[image]